# Accessing to the `latest` record stored in DB table right after recording it

Tags: mysql, database, laravel

In Laravel After recording last row to a DB table, can I safely access same recorded data right after recording it by calling `latest()` queries? Because transactions by other users may occur at the same time, and it may not really be the last record anymore?

**Edit:**

For example:

```
Public function StoreNotif($data){

auth()->user()->Notif()->create(store $data here..)

}

Public function SendNotif(){

$data="123";

$this->StoreNotif($data)

event(new Notification(stored Notif instance?));

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot rely on the database to return the record from your current script.

The `->latest()` method will always sort the records with the most recent `created_at` date first.
https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset

But you haven't provided any code or explanation as to why this is a concern.  If you just created a new record, why do you need to query it again?  You should already have access to an instance of the model.

**EDIT:** I've made a few edits to demonstrate how you would pass the model from a controller to an event as referenced in the comments. Please post your code if you want more specific help.

**SomeController.php**

```php
function store()
{
    $model = Model::create([
        'some_data' => 1 
    ]);

    // fire an event with the newly created model
    event(new SomeEvent($model));

    dd($model);
}

------------------------

Model {
    // ... 
    attributes: [
        'id' => 101,
        'some_data' => 1 
        'created_at' => '2019-10-06 12:48:01',
        'updated_at' => '2019-10-06 12:48:01',
    ]
    // ...
}
```

**SomeEvent.php**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use App\Model;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class SomeEvent
{
    use SerializesModels;

    public $model;

    public function __construct(Model $model)
    {
        $this->model = $model;

        // ...
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT:** Per your newly added code, you just need to pass the new model back to the original method.  You could do something like this.

```php
Public function StoreNotif($data)
{
    // add a return statement
    return auth()->user()->Notif()->create(store $data here..);
}

Public function SendNotif()
{
    $data="123";

    // store the returned data to a variable
    $model = $this->StoreNotif($data);

    // call the event with the model instance
    event(new Notification(model));
}
```

Comment: How to call current model in controller method? I need to pass an instant of current model (as you mensioned) to an event method. using `event(new MyModel())` doesnt work. I `used` needed Model in Controller head.

Comment: I've made a few edits to my answer based on my best guess of what you are asking.  Please post your code if you want more specific help.

Comment: You are very close to what i asked, and ok, i edited question and added some codes, thank you anyway.

Comment: Thank you for posting your code. See my newest edits.

Comment: I thought Store method returns only `boolean` result .. wow.. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what 'latest' is but I do know that [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/getting-unique-id.html) uses `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID` as the query to get the 'per-connection' id of the last inserted item. Under the covers it's using `mysql_insert_id` so if you are in a language that supports it, you could use that too.

Comment: Well i'm working with Laravel so i talked about it's "Eloquent"s .. edited. anyway your answer was so helpful.